# Illegal invoke-super to void groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass) from class net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ContentBuilder

Tags: android, groovy, proguard

I have created an Android app in which I am parsing the calendar events. Everything works fine if the proguard is disabled.
When I try to obfuscate my code by enabling the proguard then I am getting this error and build failed.

**Illegal invoke-super to void groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass) from class net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ContentBuilder**

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for this problem.

A code snippet where I am using the Ical4j library

```
.
.
.
Date time = cal.getTime();
Period period = new Period(new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime(time), new Dur(20, 0, 0, 0));
Filter filter = new Filter(new PeriodRule(period));
.
.
.
if (component.getProperty("ATTENDEE") != null) {
    int attendeeSize = component.getProperties("ATTENDEE").size();
    for (int a = 0; a < attendeeSize; a++) {
        attendee = (net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Attendee) component.getProperties("ATTENDEE").get(a);
        if (attendee.getParameter("CN") != null)
            attendeeEmail = attendeeEmail + "\n" + attendee.getParameter("CN").getValue();
    }
} 
.
.
.
```

This is my proguard-rules.pro

```
#noinspection ShrinkerUnresolvedReference

-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*, Signature, Exception
-dontshrink
-dontwarn net.fortuna.ical4j.model.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class com.example.elcapi.jnielc.** {public private *;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.File_Browser.FilePicker.** {public <fields>;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.FlightBoard.Data.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.InAppBilling.Inventory.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.InAppBilling.IabResult.** {public <fields>;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.InAppBilling.IabException.** {public <fields>;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.InAppBilling.IabBroadcastReceiver.** {public <fields>;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.MainScreenButtons.Buttons.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.roomdisplay.powerbutton.AppContext.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.BookRoomNowData.** {*;}
-keepnames class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.chkInternetConn.**
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_exchange.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_exchange.frag_exchange.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_exchange.frag_exchange_find_resource** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_exchange.frag_exchange_resource** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_server.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_server.frag_server.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_google.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_google.closeOldChannel.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_google.MakeRequestTask.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Conn_frag_google.openNewChannel.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.DeviceName.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.ExcCurrentMeetings.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.ExcNextMeetings.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.fireBase.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.FirebaseAnalyticsClass.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.FirebaseInstanceIdService.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.GoogleEvents.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.LogIn1.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.MailGun.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.MailGunAtteendees.** {*;}
-keep class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.MainActivity.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.SendGMailTask.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.SendMailGunTask.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.SendMailGunTaskAttendees.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.SendMailTask.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.SetDemoServer.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.TLSSocketFactory.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class culha.MeetingRoomSchedule.Toggle.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.** {*;}

-keep class com.google.firebase.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.jakewharton.** {public *;}
-keep public class net.openid.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.android.volley.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.github.** {public *;}
-keep public class org.glassfish.hk2.** {public *;}
-keep public class net.sargue.mailgun.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.wdullaer.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.google.api.** {public *;}
-keep public class pub.devrel.easypermissions.** {public *;}
-keep public class biweekly.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.google.firebase.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.android.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.independentsoft.** {public *;}
-keep public class androidx.** {public *;}
-keep public class android.support.** {public *;}
-keep public class javax.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.sun.mail.** {public *;}
-keep public class com.independentsoft.** {public  *;}
-keep public class org.apache.** {public  *;}
-keep public class net.margaritov.** {public *;}
-keep public class net.fortuna.ical4j.** {public  *;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by removing **-dontshrink** from the proguard-rules.pro. Hope this will help someone else facing this problem.